# Azure Queue client Dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an azure application developed using MVC Web API, and it uses Ninject as the dependency injection framework, here there are number of queues used to communicate with the other worker roles responsible for the background processing.

To be able to unit test I decided to wrap the QueueClient with class called QueueClientWrapper and use an interface named IQueueClientWrapper

the class and interface looks like follows,

```
public interface IQueueClientWrapper
{
    void Send<T>(T message);
}

public class QueueClientWrapper : IQueueClientWrapper
{
    private QueueClient _queueClient;

    public QueueClientWrapper(QueueClient queueClient)
    {
        _queueClient = queueClient;
    }

    public void Send<T>(T message)
    {
        _queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage(message));
    }
}
```

However the limitation of this approach is I need to pass the QueueClient into the constructor, which is not possible with the Ninject.

So I was thinking changing the interface like,

```
public interface IQueueClientWrapper
{
    void Send<T>(string connectionString,string queueName,T message);
}
```

so that I can use Ninject to inject the QueueClientWrapper without needing to pass constructor argument,

The issue I have now is, usually it's not recommended to create multiple queue client objects and we have to re-use same instance. So what's the best way to address this (I thought of using a static Hashtable and use to store queue name, queue client pairs, but I'm not very happy with that approach either)?

Comment: why can't you pass the `QueueClient into the constructor with NInject? Could you pass a `QueueClientFactory` instead and then have this return the same instance of the queue every time the `QueueClientWrapper` asks it for a `QueueClient`?

Comment: But Queue name would be different in different situations, I need to inject wrapper for Queue A and Queue B where clients are different, how do I address that?

Comment: Can't you have a method on the QueueClientFactory which gets a QueueClient by name

Comment: It's possible, again we are down to the same thing, having to store list of queue clients in a map?

Answer (score 2):

**Dealing with Dependency Injection and Azure Queue**

This question is from 2014, **but here is a 2022 answer**

You will need these 2 official azure extensions :

1. Azure.Storage.Queues (Contains the queue service)
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Azure (Contains helpers for the `Startup.cs`)

Add this line to your `Startup.cs` in the `Configure` method :

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
   builder.AddQueueServiceClient(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureWebJobsStorage"));

});
```

And the `constructor` where you want the service :

```
public QueueHandlingService(QueueServiceClient queueClient)
{
  _queueClient = queueClient;
  //Or _queueClient = queueClient.GetQueueClient("myqueue-items");
}
```

Here are the docs for :

[AddAzureClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.azureclientservicecollectionextensions.addazureclients?view=azure-dotnet)

[AddQueueServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.queueclientbuilderextensions.addqueueserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Call `.ConfigureOptions(options => options.MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64)` if `QueueServiceClient` is used in an Azure Function.